# Unable to Upload m4a files to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload some contents to firebase storage, All the `jpg` are uploaded, but the m4a files never upload.

Image for reference
[image]

This is my code for button click and upload :

```
Button uploadBtn = findViewById(R.id.uploadBtn);
uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Recordings");
        if (dir.exists()) {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                // Skip if the file is a directory
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Check if file size is less than 5 MB
                double fileSizeInBytes = file.length();
                double fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024);
                if (fileSizeInMB < 5) {
                    // Upload file to Firebase Storage
                    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    final String filePath = fileUri.getPath();
                    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

                    final StorageReference recordingsRef = storageRef.child("Recordings/" + filePath);

                    // Check if the file already exists in the database
                    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Recordings");
                    dbRef.orderByChild("path").equalTo(filePath).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                // File does not exist, upload it
                                StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
                                        .setContentType("application/octet-stream") // Set content type to generic binary data
                                        .build();
                                UploadTask uploadTask = recordingsRef.putFile(fileUri, metadata);

                                // Get the download URL of the uploaded file and save it to Firebase Realtime Database
                                uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            throw task.getException();
                                        }
                                        return recordingsRef.getDownloadUrl();
                                    }
                                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                                            String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                                            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                                            data.put("path", filePath);
                                            data.put("url", downloadUri.toString());
                                            data.put("time", currentTime);
                                            dbRef.push().setValue(data);
                                        } else {
                                            // Handle failures
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + databaseError.getDetails(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

    }
});
```

This is my rules :

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Kindly let me know what is the issue, or how non image files can be uploaded. Nothing is print on log or in toast message as well.

Comment: Is the `m4a` file less than 5 Mega?

Comment: yes Sir, its only 1.3 mb

Comment: Which Toast message is displayed?

Comment: i found the fix, needed to use SAF